# Python re.sub Regex to replace certain character

Tags: python, regex

I would like to use `re.sub` to replace certain characters.

For example

`this is 2Z` or `this is 0.2Z`

I would like to change it to

`this is 2 oz` or `this is 0.2 oz`

but if the sentence is `this is cZ` it should stay as `this is cZ`

So basically I only want to replace the `Z` after numbers.

I have been stuck which I think it should be easy to figure out. This is what I have now:

`newstr = re.sub(r'([0-9]+(?=Z))', r' oz ',str1)` this code replaces the number instead of 'z'

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
newstr = re.sub(r'(?<=\d)Z', r' oz', str1)
newstr = re.sub(r'(?<=\d)Z\b', r' oz', str1) # If no letter, digit or _ is allowed after Z
newstr = re.sub(r'(?<=\d)Z(?![A-Za-a])', r' oz', str1) # If no letter is allowed after Z
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/iHHhQZ/1)

**Details**

- `(?<=\d)` - a position immediately preceded with a digit
- `Z` - a `Z` letter
- `\b`  - word boundary, `Z` is matched if it is not followed with a word char (letter, digit or underscore)
- `(?![A-Za-a])` - no ASCII letter is allowed after `Z`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out. You can use a look behind to match any `'Z'` that follows a digit `\d` with `(?<=\d)Z`

```
import re

str1 = "this is 2Z"
str2 = "this is cZ"

remove_Z = lambda str1: re.sub(r"(?<=\d)Z","",str1)

new_str = remove_Z(str1)
new_str2 = remove_Z(str2)

print(new_str)
print(new_str2)
```

Live Code -> https://onlinegdb.com/SJgQADNoU